# Serverpod: is it possible to upload files right on my server

Tags: flutter, dart, serverpod

Is it possible to upload files directly on my server, not on a third-party cloud storage like AWS or Google Cloud, or to send it to the server for further processing (resizing, cropping, reformatting etc.) without storing?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can , there is a DockerFile in your project that you can put it at any system that docker is installed on .
It's true that there is a lack of information about serverpod , but I think they will make it easier in the future and the documentation will be good also .